# Sum two centesimal times

Tags: php, time

I found this code but there is an error I can't found

```
function sum_time($tempo1, $tempo2) {
    $times = array($tempo1, $tempo2);
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $tempo)
    {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode('.', $tempo);
        $seconds += $hour*3600;
        $seconds += $minute*60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }
    $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
    $seconds -= $hours*3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
    $seconds -= $minutes*60;
    // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
    return sprintf('%02d.%02d.%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}

echo sum_time('3.0.00', '4.83.00');
```

the result is 08.23.00 instead of 7.83.00

Probably the problem is the code sums times in hh.mm.ss while I want to sum tims in hh.cc (hours.cents)

Comment: Erm... 7.83? As in 7 hours, **83 minutes**?

Comment: 7 hours, 83 cents

Comment: The code does calculation in seconds (actual time addition), not in fractions. As far as the code is concerned, it's working as expected, you're just feeding it unsupported values.

Comment: And then the seconds are also hundredths of a minute? Or these are 60 per minute again? (?)

Comment: cents are per 60 minutes. for example 30 minutes are 50 cents or 10 minutes are 17 cents. Can someone modify the code to work with hours and cents? Thank you

Comment: Ro was asking what the rules are for seconds. It seems to me you have no use of seconds anyway.

Comment: Yes, you're right, no seconds, only hours and cents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to not use seconds but cents like this,

```php
<?php
function sum_time($tempo1, $tempo2) {
    $times = array($tempo1, $tempo2);

    $hours = 0;
    $cents = 0;

    foreach ($times as $tempo)
    {
        list($hour, $cent) = explode('.', $tempo);
        $hours += $hour;
        $cents += $cent;
    }

    $hours += floor($cents / 100);
    $cents = $cents % 100;

    // return "{$hours}:{$cents}";
    return sprintf('%02d.%02d', $hours, $cents);
}

echo sum_time('3.0', '4.83');
```